# How to act on an async delegate function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently implementing against an internal SDK with delegation in swift.

The current process for performing an action

1.) Initiate 'start' which will call the delegate
2.) My implemented delegate method will make an API call for a token
3.) The token is then used to make subsequent requests within my action.

The issue that I have is that I can't pass a closure/callback into the start process which is obviously async but then how do i await the completion of the delegate method all within the same function?

I'm thinking notifications might be the answer but I'm not a swift ninja.

So... (pseudocode)

```
func performAction() {

  internalSDK.start()
  // calls my implemented delegate
  // sets the token on self

  doActionUsingTheTokenRetrievedInMyDelegateMethod(token: self.token)
}
```

It feels like I need some kind of await or an observer which is then removed at the end of the call.

It should also be noted that the delegate method is generic so I can't implement the code within the method itself.

Comment: Why don't you put this `doActionUsingTheTokenRetrievedInMyDelegateMethod(token: self.token)` inside your delegate method?

Comment: Yeah I can't do that as I mentioned above. The result of the token generation is used in a number of methods. So it needs to be initiated outside of the delegate

Comment: If you can't do that, what _can_ you change in the delegate method?

Comment: As I mentioned the delegate needs to retrieve a token. Outside of that I can add anything that's necessary to notify the calling function of completion. But I don't know what to add - hence the question :)

Comment: Can you post the code for your implemented delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make do with the simplest possible tools available, e.g. a property observer on the token, like so:

```
class Foo {
    var token: Token {
        didSet {
            doActionUsingTheTokenRetrievedInMyDelegateMethod(token: self.token)
        }
    }

    func performAction() {
      internalSDK.start()
      // calls my implemented delegate
      // sets the token on self
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was going down that route myself but unfortunately it has the same side effects of running this within the delegate method. In that the token can be set as the result of a number of different calls.